# How to create constraint unique multiple columns with specific value for 1 colums in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

I have already created constraint unique with 5 columns like below :

```
 ALTER TABLE CAMPAIGN_MSISDN add CONSTRAINT ADWISER_UNIQUE UNIQUE (campaign_id, 
 msisdn, running_date, time_frame, status);
```

This status has 5 values in the form of enum. 
But I want ADWISER_UNIQUE just checking constraint in 2/5 status instead all of status. How can I do it.
Thanks all!

Comment: What do you mean my "just checking constraint in 2/5 status instead all of status"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `unique index` with the condition. see the following example:

```
SQL> create table test123 (col1 number, col2 number, col3 number);

Table created.

SQL> -- You need something like this (solution)
SQL> create unique index test123_ix01 on test123(case when col3 in (1,2) then col1 end,
  2                                              case when col3 in (1,2) then col2 end,
  3                                              case when col3 in (1,2) then col3 end);

Index created.

SQL>
```

Now, Let's check if it works or not:

```
SQL> insert into test123 values (1,2,3);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test123 values (1,2,3);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test123 values (1,2,1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test123 values (1,2,2); -- this is of your interest -- see col3 value

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test123 values (1,2,2); -- this is of your interest -- see col3 value
insert into test123 values (1,2,2)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEJASH.TEST123_IX01) violated


SQL>
SQL> select * from test123;

      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         1          2          3
         1          2          1
         1          2          2

SQL>
```

Whoa!!! It restricted multiple values of `col3` when `col3` is 2 and it will behave the same in case of `col3` is 1. all other statuses are allowed to be inserted multiple times.

Cheers!!

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.